# Passing an arbitrary set of parameters to numpy.meshgrid without hardcoding

Tags: function, parameters, automation

Is it possible to pass a set of parameters to the `numpy.meshgrid` function without having to type out each parameter?

I want to pass something like a list comprehension to this function so that instead of writing code that looks like this:

`mg = numpy.meshgrid(x1,x2,x3,...,xn)`

I can write something that iterates through these functions and feeds it to the function like this pseudo-code:

`mg = numpy.meshgrid([parameter_x for parameter_x in parameter_set])`

and yields the same result.

I attempted to research this problem and read the man-page for `numpy.meshgrid` for clues to no avail and I could not find a way to implement this behaviour. If anyone could point me to a resource where I can learn about this or have a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question.

To reference an arbitrary set you can use a list comprehension to create the list of parameters, then access it using a `*` prefix like so:

`parameter_set = {p1,p2,...,p3}`

`args = [parameter_x for parameter_x in parameter_set]`

`mg = numpy.meshgrid(*args)`